# Wordpress Avada Theme remove border

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How do I remove in Wordpress `Avada` Theme the top borders, which automatically appear everywhere and look like this:

[image]

I can remove them in Chrome dev tools just like this:

[image]

But if I put e.g. this css code inside the Avada themes custom css, it is still there:

```
#main .fusion-row {
    border-top: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to consider the `page id` in the css:

```
.page-id-xxxx #main .fusion-row {
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tru and edit the border thickness as it is:

```
#main .fusion-row {
    border-top: 0px solid #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: This is almost the same as what I already tried. It doesnt work like this for whatever reason

Answer (score 0):

```
 #main .fusion-row {
       display: none !important;
   }
```

Use this CSS line in your additional CSS field

Or

You can go to the theme editor and look for header.php file look for header code remove it.